# android code to how to logout from twitter

Tags: android, twitter, logout

I have an application from where i logged through twitter. But I cant logout from that.
At first time in which id i logged in all the time it opens the same login id.

I want a logout option should their so that I can logged out from twitter and can login through different id also.

Anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the security token from oauth and you are logged out :-)
Otherwise it lasts forever, I don't recall seeing a logout api but there might be one...  All I do is forget the token and get a new one on the next login.